# ASP.net page refresh after click button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just want to refresh the page after a click on the ASP button "VALIDER".

```
<asp:Button Text="VALIDER" ID="lbSuiteOuvragesNContr" 
            runat="server" onclick="lbSuiteOuvragesNContr_Click" />




protected void lbSuiteOuvragesNContr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BoProcesVerbaux.ModifierInspectionGpeOuvrageComposition(uc_OuvragesNonControlesV41.ListeInspection);
    this.IdPv = IdProcesVerbal;
    uc_OuvragesNonControlesV42.IdPV = idPv;
    InitialiserPage(this.IdPv);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "refresh"? That code will post back and do a refresh already.

Comment: Like if i do F5.

Comment: Do you want your button to execute the click handler or do you want it to do a reload without executing`lbSuiteOuvragesNContr_Click`? You can't have both. If you don't want to run the server-side code just execute some javascript instead: `Location.reload();`

Comment: Thank you evryone i find my solution !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this statement.

```
 Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

Comment: Thank you evryone i find my solution !

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what your server event is doing , you can try for refreshing the page.

```
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
```

but maybe you just mean to create full post back or using update panel to update your view?

Comment: Thank you evryone i find my solution !